# Rails: How to use gem Meta-tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-tags

Has anyone tried to use meta-tags for Rails?

https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags

What does this mean?

Which syntax do I need to use?

Where to put it?

Little docs about it.

```
set_meta_tags :title => 'Member Login'
# <title>Some Page Title</title>
set_meta_tags :site => 'Site Title', :title => 'Member Login'
# <title>Site Title | Page Title</title>
set_meta_tags :site => 'Site Title', :title => 'Member Login', :reverse => true
# <title>Page Title | Site Title</title>
```

Comment: I would say that the documentation on the github page is actually pretty good. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Yule I want to have share buttons in some resources, and pass meta-tags to them, but I don't know where to put the sintax on their docs or how to put it. Does everything go in the views?

Answer (score 12):

You may miss the [MetaTags Usage](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags#metatags-usage) section in meta-tags [README](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags).

Here is an example:

*In layout:*

```
<head>
  <%= display_meta_tags %>
  ...
</head>
```

*In controller:*

```
def show
  set_meta_tags title: "your title",
                keywords: "your keywords",
                description: "your description"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the `head` of the view. If your using HAML, that would look like

```
= set_meta_tags site: 'My Site'
```

and if your using ERB

```
<%= set_meta_tags site: 'My Site' %>
```

Comment: And if I'm using normal erb?

<%= set_meta_tags :title => 'Member Login' %> ?